# ProgressBar en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy desarrollando una interfaz con WPF y C# que busca de forma recursiva y muestra todos los archivos que tengan una determinada extensión dentro de un determinado directorio seleccionado por el usuario. 
Esta parte ya la tengo lista y funcionando correctamente.
Lo que quiero ahora es disponer de una barra de progreso que me muestre el nivel de progreso de esta tarea, ya que en el caso de búsqueda de los archivos en el directorio C, tarda bastante.

¿Como podría implementar esto? Una barra de progreso que me indique el progreso del método hasta que finalice.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: mejor usar algun tipo de spinner. Una barra de progreso, si no sabes el total antes de comenzar, no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: ¿Usas MVVM? Algún framework en específico?

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un link con una pequeña explicación de cómo usar el ProgressBar en WPF.
Parece algo tedioso de entender pero es bastante sencillo, si tienes algún que otro problema, coméntamelo y echamos un vistazo al código.

Link: [Tutorial básico ProgressBar](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/es/65/controles-adicionales/the-progressbar-control/)